# jQuery - Get single count of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have code which sends an `ajax` request when you search an input box. I then also want to send filters to my web-server based on certain `<div>`s which were clicked. The snippet looks like this (without the ajax request)

```js
$('.selector').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $('.selector.active').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).parents()[1]);
  });
});
```

```css
.filter .label {
  padding: 4px 8px;
  background-color: #707070;
}
.filter .content {
  max-width: 96px;
  max-height: 0px;
  margin: 0px 10px 0px 6px;
  background-color: #808080;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.filter:hover .content {
  max-height: 256px;
}
.content .selector {
  background-color: #369;
  padding: 8px 4px;
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: .1s !important;
}
.content .selector:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: #369;
}
.content .active {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  color: #369;
}
.content .active:hover {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  color: black;
}
.filter .bar {
  height: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #808080;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="temps" class="filter">
  <div class="label">
    <span>The Temps:</span>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="selector">Temp1</div>
    <div class="selector">Temp2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
<div id="others" class="filter">
  <div class="label">
    <span>The Temps:</span>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="selector">Other1</div>
    <div class="selector">Other2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

What this returns is: each time one of the `.selector`s is clicked, it `log`s all the `.selector`s which have the class `.active` - it logs the parents of that `.selector` two levels up (the `.filter`).

**I am trying to figure out how to get only *one* instance of each `#id` of the filter** i.e. if both of the `temps selectors` are `active`, it will log:

```
<div id="temps" class="filter">
<div id="temps" class="filter">
```

**I only want to have it send one - I want to get the "unique value" (to use some SQL lingo) more or less**

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Push each item to an array, then use `$.unique()` to log unique items only to the console:

```js
var arr = [];

$('.selector').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $('.selector.active').each(function() {
    arr.push($(this).parents()[1]);
  });

  console.log($.unique(arr));
});
```

```css
.filter .label {
  padding: 4px 8px;
  background-color: #707070;
}
.filter .content {
  max-width: 96px;
  max-height: 0px;
  margin: 0px 10px 0px 6px;
  background-color: #808080;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.filter:hover .content {
  max-height: 256px;
}
.content .selector {
  background-color: #369;
  padding: 8px 4px;
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: .1s !important;
}
.content .selector:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: #369;
}
.content .active {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  color: #369;
}
.content .active:hover {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  color: black;
}
.filter .bar {
  height: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #808080;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="temps" class="filter">
  <div class="label">
    <span>The Temps:</span>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="selector">Temp1</div>
    <div class="selector">Temp2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
<div id="others" class="filter">
  <div class="label">
    <span>The Temps:</span>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="selector">Other1</div>
    <div class="selector">Other2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

**EDIT** As of jQuery 3.0, `$.uniqueSort()` is the method to use.

> As of jQuery 3.0, this method is deprecated and just an alias of jQuery.uniqueSort(). Please use that method instead.
>
> - [***jQuery docs***](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/)

In the above example, jQuery 2.1.1 is included, so `$.unique()` is used, as `$.uniqueSort()` is not a function.

Comment: thank you! this works. I am going to use `.uniqueSort` as the jQuery site says `unique` is deprecated per jQuery 3.0, but thank you for leading me towards this!

Comment: @4lackof Thank you for informing me it's deprecated! I'll edit my answer

Comment: @guest271314 thank you for your answer. Don't want to start a fight here, but per https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/ I quote: "As of jQuery 3.0, this method is deprecated and just an alias of jQuery.uniqueSort(). Please use that method instead."

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`.unique()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/) method built into JQuery.

Answer (score 2):

You could check existing array for element before pushing element to array using `$.grep()`, `.is()`

```js
var log = [];

$('.selector').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $('.selector.active').each(function(i, elem) {
    if (!$.grep(log, function(el) {
      return $(el).is($(elem).closest(".filter")[0])
    }).length) {
      log.push($(this).closest(".filter")[0])
    }
  });
  console.log(log);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="temps" class="filter">
  <div class="label">
    <span>The Temps:</span>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="selector">Temp1</div>
    <div class="selector">Temp2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
<div id="others" class="filter">
  <div class="label">
    <span>The Temps:</span>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="selector">Other1</div>
    <div class="selector">Other2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

You could check existing array for element before pushing element to array using `Array.prototype.indexOf()`

```js
var log = [];

$('.selector').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $('.selector.active').each(function() {
    if (log.indexOf($(this).closest(".filter")[0]) === -1) {
      log.push($(this).closest(".filter")[0])
    }
  });
  console.log(log);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="temps" class="filter">
  <div class="label">
    <span>The Temps:</span>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="selector">Temp1</div>
    <div class="selector">Temp2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
<div id="others" class="filter">
  <div class="label">
    <span>The Temps:</span>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="selector">Other1</div>
    <div class="selector">Other2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @4lackof See updated post. Corrected `$.grep()`, `.is()` approach, included `.indexOf()` approach